Replacing 2 way light switch
I have a 2 way light switch. I bought a new one, but the number of slots on the back seems different. The old one has 2 slots at the top and the bottom for each switch. The new one has 2 at the top and one at the bottom.
Why is this? Have I bought the wrong switch?
New:

Old:


Is the switch on the left in your bottom photo (right-hand when installed in the wall) the only switch-that controls its light, or is it part of a multi-way setup?

I think you have the wrong switch. The label INTER on the old switches indicates that these are intermediate switches in a multi-way setup. If so, you need to replace with a 2-gang intermediate unit such as https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/CM2723.html

Neither of the existing answers explain what they think that you mean by a two-way switch.  I'm going to explain what I would mean if I used the term.  You would better be able to tell if that's the way that you are using it.
The kind of switch that I learned as a "two-way" was one that had an always hot wire coming in and a switched hot wire going out to the light (or other load).  The simplest switch, it was either on or off.  It depended on no other switch for function.
Three-way switches work in pairs.  An always hot going to one of the pair; two travelers coming out and going to the other three-way in the pair; switched hot coming from that and going to load.  Whether it's on or off depends on both switches.
If you want more than two switches, you add four-ways in between the three-ways.  Travelers in and travelers out.
A straightforward way to wire this is so that if there are an even number of switches up (0, 2, etc.) then it's switched off.  An odd number and it's switched on.  You could also wire it the other way, although I find that more confusing.  If you want to switch it from one to the other, pick a switch and swap two travelers on one side.  You may have to look at a wiring diagram for the switch to understand which wires are on the same side.
What you have (old switch) match what I would expect to be called four-way switches.  As this answer notes, those can also reasonably be called intermediate switches (because they are always between other switches, never at the end).  You would replace these with new four-way switches.
This answer suggests that it is possible that these are two-way switches that switch both hot and neutral.  I've never seen that, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't exist.  If this is the case, you could replace the old switch with standard two-way switches on the hot and wirenut the neutral wires together.
Your new switches look like three-way switches.  They're the wrong switch for either situation.  That seems like the answer to the question.  Yes, that's the wrong switch.  However, there is an implicit question of what would be the right switch.  I continue to lean toward the four-way, but I can't rule out the hot/neutral two-way.
At this point, it may be worth having an electrician finish.  Figuring out which wires are hot and which neutral is non-trivial.  Particularly since some of the wires may be sometimes on and sometimes off.
If you want to continue on a DIY basis, you may want to ask a new question about how to distinguish between hot and neutral in the case where either might be behind a switch.  Or perhaps show those pictures to someone at your local hardware store.  Local proprietors would be more likely to know about local wiring standards than people on the internet who might be anywhere on the globe (i.e. not necessarily in the same country as you).
If all the switches are currently working, you could also check the behavior of the switches.  Do any other switches control the same lights?  Can any switch in the group turn the light on or off?  I.e. does flipping the switch change the light always?  Or only when another switch is in a particular position.
If those are four-way switches, then they should be used in groups of three or more.  Two-way switches would be used singly.  Of course, that's assuming that they're wired in what I would consider a normal fashion.  There's nothing stopping people from wiring two-way switches in series so that both have to be on for the light to be on (except perhaps code restrictions in some situations).

One thing I picked up recently is that what the USA calls a "3-way" switch is called "2-way" in Britain.

Assuming you are in the UK and those are old wire colors (red for Live, black for Neutral), then your old switch is a 2-pole switch that switches both live and neutral wires.
Your new switch is a single-pole switch that works only on one wire (preferably the live one), but it can be used in your installation without issue.
For each of the two switches, connect the black wires together with a wirenut (or similar device to connect wires together permanently). Connect 1 red wire to the terminal marked "Common" and the other to the terminal marked "1Way".

The two switches in the bottom photo are wired differently, so connecting blacks together is not correct. Left-hand may be an intermediate switch in a multi-switch setup. Right-hand is a simple switch. Also we don't use wire nuts in the UK

@rhellen, the only difference between the switches is that the wires have been mirrored. For a 2-pole switch, that doesn't make any functional difference.

you're right, I couldn't see the wires in the bottom clearly, but if the switches are intermediates, not 2-pole, (I can't find images of the backs of switches, but the label INTER is a clue) then they'll need to be replaced with intermediates. Connecting the blacks and switching the reds will result in confusing operation (this switch will be either be a master or irrelevant depending on the positions of the other switches)
